Two minipage with horizontal lines and a vertical line
I'm trying to make a custom command with two parameters that let me input the blue text and the black text, then output something like this with a vertical line in the middle separating the text
I have tried this:
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.3\linewidth} 
some text 
\end{minipage} 
\hfill\vline\hfill 
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.6\linewidth} 
some text 
\end{minipage} 

but the spacing between minipage is too wide and the text is not right alined.
How can I achieve this, any help is much appreciated.

Please show what you tried. For example can you write the minipages without the lines?

I have tried this:
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.3\linewidth}
some text
\end{minipage}
\hfill\vline\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.6\linewidth}
some text
\endgroup
\end{minipage}
but the spacing between minipage is too wide and the text is not right alined.

please add this to your question and also add a class etc. so that people can compile the code.

I'd go with a simple tabular.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,hhline}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{explanation}{O{0.3}m}
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{
    p{\dimeval{#1\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth/2}}
    |
    p{\dimeval{\columnwidth-#1\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth/2}}
  }
  \hline
  \raggedleft\textcolor{Turquoise}{#2} &
}{%
  \tabularnewline
  \hhline{~|-}
  \end{tabular}\par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{explanation}{Test Procedure for a Single Mean (Variance Known)}
Some text before the display
\[
z=\frac{a}{b} \text{ or } z=\frac{x}{y}
\]
some text follows some text follows some text follows
some text follows some text follows some text follows
some text follows some text follows some text follows
some text follows some text follows some text follows
\end{explanation}

\begin{explanation}[0.25]{Test Procedure for a Single Mean (Variance Known)}
\noindent\[
z=\frac{a}{b} \text{ or } z=\frac{x}{y}
\]
some text follows some text follows some text follows
some text follows some text follows some text follows
some text follows some text follows some text follows
some text follows some text follows some text follows
\end{explanation}

\end{document}


Note \noindent\[ if you really want to start a paragraph with a math display.

I'd suggest some kind of table. Here an example with tabularray:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[.2\textwidth,halign=r]Q[.8\textwidth-24.4pt]},
    column{1}={fg=blue},
    hlines,
    vline{2}={solid}
  }
  #1 & #2\\
  \end{tblr}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\foo{%
  blue blue blue blue blue
}{%
  \[a=b\]
  black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black black
}%

\end{document}


